# Traversing through a set from a particular index to a particular index

Tags: c++, set, traversal

I have an iterator. Say I need to traverse the set not from the beginning but from some particular point. Also it is quite difficult for me to get the values stored in the sets as they are pointers. So how to i modify my code to traverse through my sets from a point that is not the begining.  ?

Here is the code:

```
for(iter=make.at(level).begin();iter!=make.at(level).end();iter++)
{
Function(*iter);
}
```

Using this gives an error:

```
for(iter=make.at(level).begin()+10;iter!=make.at(level).end();iter++)
    {
    Function(*iter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different types of iterators: `ForwardIterator`, `BidirectionalIterator`, and `RandomAccessIterator`.

`ForwardIterator` allows you to move forward only, using the increment operator. `BidirectionalIterator` allows both directions. `RandomAccessIterator` allows any advancement, including `operator+` and `operator-`.

The one you're thinking in terms of is `RandomAccessIterator`, like the one found in `std::vector`. What `std::set` uses, though, is the `BidirectionalIterator`. That means you can only increment and decrement.

Therefore, you need to make your iterator outside of your loop and advance it forward ten times. To make it simple, `std::advance` does this, and has different compatibility for `BidirectionalIterator`, as well as `ForwardIterator` (linear time because of only one increment at a time), and `RandomAccessIterator` (constant time due to operator+).

```
std::set<T>::iterator iter = make.at(level).begin(); //more C++03 way
auto iter = std::begin (make.at(level)); //more C++11 way
std::advance (iter, 10); //start iterator 10 elements past beginning
for (...)
```

Comment: iter=make.at(level).begin();
advance(iter,10);
for(;iter!=make.at(level).end();iter++)
{
Function(*iter);
}

But this ain't working.

Comment: @user1506031, Could you produce a small sample that replicates the problem and ask about that? One note, though, is that you should get in the habit of using `++iter`, rather than `iter++` with iterators (and it really doesn't hurt with other things as well).

Comment: Got it to work in this way only now.. :) Had the problem withe the range check.